# how can I insert into Stringp[

Tags: android, android-listview

I have currently predefined data

```
String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile", "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu",
                "Windows7", "Max OS X", "Linux", "OS/2", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X", "Linux", "OS/2", "Ubuntu",
                "Windows7", "Max OS X", "Linux", "OS/2", "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile" };
```

I want to insert into values from array of object

```
List<Scores> myScore = db.getAllScore();


        for (Scores cn : scor)
        {
            // how can I insert it into values

        }
```

Comment: y dont u use arraylist?

Comment: i have to use this, so Its not possible?

Comment: @meWantToLearn Sorry did not understand what exactly you want to do

Comment: @meWantToLearn have you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

```
List<Score> myScore = db.getAllScore();

        for (int i = 0,j=value.length; i < myScore.size(); i++,j++) {
            value[j]=myScore.get(i);
        }
```